# Ignore last value if it was similar to one before in, Operator Combine framework

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a Boolean property with published, then I subscribe to that publisher, every time the boolean value changed, my publisher sends a new value

```
@Published var booleanProperty: Bool = false
let subscription = $booleanProperty
     .sink { newBool in
        print(newBool)
     }
```

my question is, is there an **operator** to ignoring the publishing value if it was similar to the latest one.

like publisher send [true,true, false, false]
I just get [true,false]

Comment: `.removeDuplicates()`?

Comment: no, .removeDuplicates() check all the published values and not the latest one

Comment: _No_, please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204745-removeduplicates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`removeDuplicates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204745-removeduplicates):

```
let subscription = $booleanProperty
    .removeDuplicates()
    .sink { newBool in
        print(newBool)
    }
```

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Publishes only elements that don’t match the ***previous*** element.
>
> [...]
>
> Because the two-element memory considers only the current element and the previous element, ***the operator prints the final 0 in the example data since its immediate predecessor is 4***.
>
> ```
> let numbers = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0]
> cancellable = numbers.publisher
>     .removeDuplicates()
>     .sink { print("\($0)", terminator: " ") }
>  
> // Prints: "0 1 2 3 4 0"
> ```

Comment: what about you send another 4 after zero? it will not publish.
[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]
removeDuplicates: [0,1]
I want:
[0,1,0,1,0]
I want it just checks the diffrene from that last emitted value

Comment: @connorhabibi Did you even try running any code? If you run `[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0].publisher.removeDuplicates().sink { (x) in print(x) }` in a playground, it will print `0 1 0 1 0` each number on a different line. _Try it._

Comment: you totally right and I just test it, I was thinking another way. cheers